# Confusion on Propositional Logic Question

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have this proposition:$(\forall a\in \Re )(\forall b \in\Re)(e^{a+bi}=2i\Rightarrow a=ln2,b=\frac{\pi}{2})$ Where I am asked to find what is false about this, 2 things came to mind, the initial part ofthe proposition states that that $a$ and $b$ are said to be some arbitrary value and we are then told $a$ and $b$ have this explicit value, second of all theta isn't given as $\frac{\Pi}{2}+2\Pi n$. The hint was that we had to introduce a quantifier after $\Rightarrow$ regarding $n$ being part of the real numbers.

Comment: $e^{a+ib}$ is a number and not a statment.

Comment: @mauro how would you change the proposition then?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to assert... $\Rightarrow$ is a propositional connective: it "connects" sentences, and translate "if..., then...". It has no sense to say "if John, then it will rain tomorrow".

Comment: I can't think of a single thing to write after $\Rightarrow$ , the hint says something about n being any integer value...

Comment: Where is $n$ ? And *theta* ?

Comment: Maybe you are working with [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)... Maybe you need $e^{a+ib}=$?

Comment: The question is asking me to re write the part after $\Rightarrow$ So that it it correct and the hint says I need to use the quantifier ($\exists n \in Z$)

Comment: Ok; now it seems that you have understood the difference between a sentence (formula) and a name (number) :-)

Comment: Is this proposition correct or still incorrect?

Comment: We have that $e^{a+ib}=e^ae^{ib}$.

Comment: By Euler, $e^{ib}=(\cos(b)+i \sin(b))$. Fir $b= \dfrac {\pi} {2}$ we have $\cos(b)=0$ and $\sin(b)=1$. Thus: $e^ae^{ib} = ie^a$.

Comment: You want that $i e^a=2i$, that means: $e^a=2$, i.e. $a= \ln 2$.

Comment: I completely understand that, but is the form in which the proposition is laid out technically incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've basically got the flaw in the statement, it's of course that if $b=\pi/2+2n\pi$ then $e^{a+ib}=2i$. So you can't conclude that $b=\pi/2$ from that. Your second comment indicates you're clear about that.

The quantifiers and the statement that $a$ and $b$ has specific values is not in itself a flaw. The statement says that for any $a$ and $b$ fulfilling $e^{a+ib}=2i$ you would have $a=\ln 2$ and $b=\pi/2$. It doesn't outright say that they have that value, if for example $a=b=0$ then you have that $e^{a+ib}=2i$ is false so for the implication to hold the statement $a=\ln 2$ and $b=\pi/2$ is allowed to be false (or true).

In fact the negation of the statement is that there exists $a$ and $b$ such that $a\ne\ln2$ or $b\ne\pi/2$ and still $e^{a+ib}=2i$. For example $b=5\pi/2$ and $a=\ln2$ would prove that the negation of the statement is true.

Comment: The hint states that "there exist" value of n, technically shouldn't it be "for all" integer values of n?

Comment: @Jan That depends on the direction of the implication. You have for all integers $n$ that if $b=\pi/2+2n\pi$ then $e^{ib}=i$, for the other way around you have that if $e^{ib}=i$ then there exists an integer $n$ such that $b=\pi/2+2n\pi$.